# How to retrive events from google calendar API fro c# .net using API key

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am able to retrieve event from google calendar API using OAuth authentication by code given [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet), but how to code for getting event information using API key.

Comment: Have you had a look at the API documentation? There is a specific entry for Events https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Comment: Yes gone through this pages but not found any code for C#.net.

Comment: only https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet I found

Comment: I am asking for API key!!!

Comment: A quick google found this: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490

Comment: I have done this step but I want code to apply in c# language to get information from google calendar API.

Answer (score 1):

API key is for use with **PUBLIC** data.  For an API key to work with a calendar I would assume said calendar would have to be set to public.

```
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
         ApiKey = "XXX",
         ApplicationName = "xyz",

        });
var events = service.Events.List("en.danish#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com").Execute();

foreach (var myEvent in events.Items)
     {
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Event: {0} Start: {1} End: {2}", myEvent.Summary, myEvent.Start.DateTime.ToString(), myEvent.End.DateTime.ToString()));
     }
```

I have an example / tutorial of accessing events on public calendars [here](http://www.daimto.com/public-google-calendars-with-c/)

I think you should consider looking at a service account instead this will allow you to grant the service account access to your calendar and you wont need to go though the Oauth2 authentication which I suspect is what you don't want to be doing.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
    CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
 };

 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
        Scopes = scopes
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

I have a tutorial on how to us a service account [here](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/#Google_CalendarAPI_Service_Account_Authentication)

Comment: I have used service account with API version 3.0 when I try to get calendar by  CalendarList calendars = request1.Execute(); it gives calendar count as 0. But id I shared service account email Id to my gmail account(xxxx@gmail.com) then I am getting the events information properly.